# Suprocess process.stdout.readline() freezes the program

Tags: python, minecraft

I am trying to make a python program communicate with a minecraft server I am hosting, but the problem I am finding is when the console output from the server, it freezes the program. I am using Popen and PIPE from subprocess, and whenever I use process.stdout.readline() it prints all the lines and when it is done, it freezes the program, and then I am not able to execute any more commands because of that.

```
def start(cmd):
    try:
        process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return process
start('java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui') # runs the minecraft server with 8GB of RAM
while True:
    print(process.stdout.readline()) # prints out every line in the server console
    readmail() # the program checks email for commands, and enters the command into the console using stdin
```

I have tried this:

```
def start(cmd):
    try:
        process = Popen(['python', '-u', cmd], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return process
```

It fixes the issue with `process.stdout.readline()`, but it gives me an error because the command is meant to be called in cmd and not with python. Does anyone know how to fix the issue with `readline()`?